# Link C# Class Library with application

Tags: c#, linker

Is it possible to link C# class library with exe application (as single file) not as .dll + .exe?

Comment: and what is your variant? must be ILMerge too? i'm looking for normal solution, not MS research hack. for example some checkbox in my project settings..

Answer (score 1):

it is possible using Ilmerge: [Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9364/Merging-NET-assemblies-using-ILMerge)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx) to combine managed DLLs with your exe after compilation.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the DLL file as a resource within the EXE, then handle the `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event and load it from the `byte[]`.

Make sure to add the handler before the JITter encounters the DLL.